# Python sum of classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, subclass, disjoint-union

I want to define a class AorB, such that all A's are AorB's, and all B's are AorB's, and these are all the AorB's. Of course, A and B should be subclasses of AorB. The problem is in `AorB.__init__`, when I can't convince self it should be something else. I can define an AorB factory, but I'd rather have AorB constructor if possible.

```
class AorB:
    def __init__(self,par):
        if par: self=A(par) #!
        else: self=B()      #!
    @staticmethod
    def from_par(par):
        if par: return A(par)
        else: return B()
class A(AorB):
    def __init__(self,par):
        self.par=par
class B(AorB):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
print(
    AorB.from_par(5),
    AorB.from_par(0),
    AorB(5),
    AorB(0),
    sep="\n")
```

I know assignment to self doesn't work here, but I just wanted to show intention. As I said, factory (from_par) works fine, I just want to call it as `AorB`, not as `AorB.from_par`.

PS. I know, `__init__` is probably too late, type of self is already determined. Feel free to use metaclasses in your answer. It's time I learn something useful about them. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, not with `__init__`. Once `__init__` is being called, the *instance is already created*.

You want a factory *function* instead:

```
class AorB: pass

class A(AorB):
    def __init__(self,par):
        self.par=par

class B(AorB):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def AorB(par):
    return A(par) if par else B()
```

From an API point of view, *there is no difference*; `AorB` is a callable that produces either an `A()` or a `B()` instance.

The other possible route involves defining a `__new__` function instead; this is the class constructor:

```
class AorB:
    def __new__(cls, par=None):
        if cls is not AorB: return super().__new__(cls)
        return super().__new__(A) if par else super().__new__(B)

class A(AorB):
    def __init__(self, par):
        self.par = par

class B(AorB):
    def __init__(self, par=None):
        pass
```

Which is just a more involved factory function, really. Note that the `__new__` method returns the result of `super().__new__` of one of the subclasses based on `par`, so both `A` and `B` will be passed a `par` parameter, wether they want one or not.

The `if cls is not AorB` line is needed to allow instantiating `A()` or `B()` directly; you can omit that line if that is not a requirement and only the `AorB` factory class is used.

Comment: "Factory function" is not good enough for me. As far as I can see, you just overwrote class AorB with def AorB. So isinstance(AorB(5),AorB) raises TypeError. :-( And I suspected `__init__` is too late. Can `__new__` and metaclasses be of any help?

Comment: @user1875565: Yes, but it's more involved and ugly.

Comment: Uglyness is in the eye of beholder. :-) One more question: can `_constructing` be avoided by having A and B their own `__new__` that calls `super().__new__`? Also, I'd rather not use default parameters, the real situation is more complicated and A and B constructors already use their fair share of `None`s. :-)

Comment: By testing for the exact type of the `cls` argument we can; I can't really test right now though.